# Read Input of different data types in one line C++

Tags: c++

The program I'm working on requires a user to input something like `i v` or `r v`, where `i` means insert, `r` means remove, and `v` would be an integer to be inserted or removed.

How can I read the input and separate it into two variables, one for the operator (as in `i` or `d`) and another for the value?

Example:

```cpp
cout << "Enter decision";
cin >> decision;

// somehow split the decision into the two variables below.

int value;
char operation;
```

Comment: Have you tried: `char operator; int number; std::cin >> operation >> number;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read something into a `std::string` (which I assume is what `decision` is), you should use `std::getline`. Formatted input, like `cin >> decision;`, will only read one word by default. Any whitespace character will make it stop reading.

```
if(std::getline(std::cin, decision)) {
    // successfully read a line
}
```

You then need to split the decision into the two variables. One simple solution is to use a `std::istringstream`. You copy the `std::string` into a `std::istringstream` and extract the values from it:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

    std::istringstream is(decision);
    if(is >> operation >> value) {
        // success
    }
```

---

Depending on the rest of the program, another option is to read directly from `std::cin` into the two variables and skip reading into `decision`:

```
if(std::cin >> operation >> value) {
    // success
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you

Comment: @FayZ Glad to hear it! You're welcome!